# Python MVC Framework vs .NET vs Rails (Middleware)

Tags: .net, python, ruby-on-rails, scalability, middleware

I'm starting one new project, and I need to choose the best technology to maintain one Middleware Layer.

This layer will offer REST and SOAP Webservices to several devices (mobile and web)

I need Speed!

I need easy setup and scalability

Regards,
Pedro

Comment: Rails and .NET are frameworks. for Python, I imagine you really mean using something like django. However, another question is really what you're actually familiar with, and if you need cross platform support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a Rails developer but I wouldnt recommend you Rails for your purpose, maybe Sinatra but Ruby in general is not known for its speed.

Considering your observations I would go for python, perhaps django is more a FrontEnd techonology. Give [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) a try, even if you dont really need its main feature (asynchronously) its known to be very fast and very easy to setup